# Windows drivers/app for apple/android headphones with remote

Tags: windows-8, drivers, android, headphones

I just got a pair of Bose QC15 that have an apple-compatible mic and remote. The remote has 2 volume buttons and a play/pause button

I'd like to use them on my laptop (Dell Win8.1) which has a combined headphone/mic socket.

The microphone works automatically. The play/pause button has worked sometimes, but mostly doesn't. The volume buttons never have.

Is there a driver that would enable the remote? Or an app that listens for a signal that comes over the mic (if that's how the apple-remote works.)

There's an equivalent cable-with-remote for android - would that work on windows? (The manufacturer didn't know.)

(This was asked in a comment previously, here: [Drivers for headphones with in-line mic and remote control](https://superuser.com/questions/607544/drivers-for-headphones-with-in-line-mic-and-remote-control#comment1040783_607634))

Comment: I looked up this particular headset.  The pictures of it, don't indicate a remote, we need more information.

Comment: Its very visible on the amazon page for it: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0054JJ0QW/ But really it doesn't matter what headset, as I guess I'm really asking about the Apple/Android hardware standard. Heres the android cable I've seen: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00EWQDC8A/